# How can I stop a CSS animation using JavaScript?

Tags: css-animations

#### CSS file

I am trying to toggle the class *pause*, but to pause the animation, the class is adding and roving from the tag. But the animation doesn't stop. Is there anything I am missing?

```
.pause{ /* Pause class which I will toggle in JavaScript */
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
    -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
    -o-animation-play-state: paused;
    animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

#### JavaScript file

```javascript
window.onload = getready;
function getready(){
    var button = document.getElementById("button");
    button.onclick = toggleplay;
    function toggleplay(){
        /* alert("button clicked"); */
        var element = document.querySelector("#sun");
        var toggle2 = document.querySelector("#stage");
        element.classList.toggle("pause");
        toggle2.classList.toggle("pause");
    }
}
```

Comment: Re *"plese tell tomorrow i have to upload my assignment tommorow"*: It is unhelpful if it is ***leaving out punctuation*** (that is ************** ***infuriating*** ************** to your readers) and is full of spelling mistakes (lack of reciprocity; while it is not strictly required, it certainly helps).

Comment: Re *"roving"*: Do you mean *"[removing](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/remove#Verb)"*?